# Is it a good idea to leave heavily downvoted challenges in the Sandbox as signposts?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/53917) posts with several downvotes (such as [the one about lolcats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9446/53917)) are signs of what the community *doesn't* like. Should we keep them to remind users about what not to "ask"?

Comment: I think generally yes, there's no need to delete sandbox posts. If the OP wants to delete them, great for them.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan On the other hand, if it's clear that the challenge in question will never make it to main, I don't think there's any harm in deleting them, and it has the benefit of making the Sandbox cleaner for those who don't have the "view deleted answers" privilege.

Comment: But those who don't have that privilege are those who most need to see what this community *doesn't* like

Comment: @Blue Yeah, _agreement_, I just wanted to say [the one about lolcats](/a/9446) does “not” exist.